# How can I elegantly secure a USB charging cable to the dashboard?

Tags: electrical

In extension of [this Q about the power outlet](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/4651/charger-doesnt-stay-put-in-cigarette-lighter-outlet) I have a related question about how to secure the USB charging cable that runs from the power plug in the cigarette lighter socket to the corner of the windshield?

I have a GPS device (or a cell phone cradle) in the corner of the windshield. I need to run a USB cable there to provide power to the device. I have a simple USB power plug for the lighter socket, and a black USB cable that is long enough to cover the distance while following the bends and curves of the dashboard -- so it's not a clothesline strung straight through the car. It *can be* neat and tidy along some ridges and edges, if I find a way to do it. **How do I affix the cable to the dashboard in a reasonably simple yet elegant way?**

Here's where I plan to have the cable (orange) from the charger (red) to the device (green). There are some seams here where plastic parts meet. I can't stuff the cable into the seam but perhaps I could stick some kind of clip into the seam to hold the cable in place along the outside of this seam?

[image]

I guess I could hot-glue the cable in place, but that would be hideous and also hard to remove. I asked my local car shop if they had some black cable clips or something self-adhesive, but they don't. They could only offer me some black masking tape to use. The shop told me that enthusiasts (who put all kinds of electricals everywhere in their cars) can disassemble the dashboard and run the cables internally. But I'm just a regular guy that doesn't want to dismantle my car :-) I don't want to end up with [something like this](http://s755.beta.photobucket.com/user/J1MMCD/media/Stripped_Dash.jpg.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would take a different route.

1. Starting at your end point (the green dot) put the connector on the dash where you want it.
2. Run the cable next to the front vent glass. Push the cable down the crack between the glass and the dash.
3. Open the door. There is usually room to run small cable down the left side. Sometimes you can tuck a single cable under the weather striping.
4. Look for a seam in the trim to make a transition under the dash.
5. Run the cable under dash along any existing harness to the center console.
6. At the center console run the cable down the back.
7. Once you reach the floor take the route you have already diagrammed. The plastic housing around the gear select will usually have some give and press into the carpet. Just push the cable under the housing.

Once the cable is ran use zip ties to secure it in place. There are some zip ties with sticky pads on them that you can use behind the A/C control area. You shouldn't have to remove anything major. Making the transition from the door jam to under the dash will be the only tricky part.

Just keep in mind that you do not want to run the cable in the way of anything that moves.

Good luck!

[image]

Comment: This is an interesting idea with less visibility. I'll grab a flashlight and study how it could be done without dismantling (too much). Thank you!

Comment: This route should be very easy. If you do need to pop the odd fascia clip it is really easy to do with a flat blade screwdriver.

Comment: The easiest way was actually down as you indicate but continue all the way to the floor, then along the door threshold and finally across in front of the driver's seat. Much simpler than my original idea, and completely invisible. Most of the cable is tucked between plastic and carpeting. Thanks!!

Comment: Glad it worked out!

Comment: This is what I do, and works great among many different makes and models.

Answer (score 0):

I use packing tape (clear, strong tape from e.g. the post office) and [epic twist ties](http://www.mec.ca/product/5026-963/nite-ize-gear-tie-reusable-rubber-twist-tie/?q=twist%2Bties) to rig up stuff like this.  I hook the twist ties into the heating vents.  The twist ties are especially useful because you can just untwist them if you want to release the cable for some reason.

Comment: I dislike packing tape on cables--the packing tape I've had to remove from cables, if it's been there a while, tends to leave sticky residue.